# サイトを丸ごとダウンロードしたい

Tags: javascript, html, css, wget

全くの素人です

このサイトをそのままの形で保存したいのですが
https://goodsmileshop.com/ja/
HTTrackで行ったら、商品ページまで保存できずに終わり商品の画像も表示されません

そこでwgetで
`wget -p -k --mirror --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows https://goodsmileshop.com/ --no-check-certificate` をつけてやってみました。

コマンドはよく分かりませんがネットでサイトそのまま再現
で検索したらこのコマンドを使えと記載がありました。
しかし、商品ページはダウンロードできず、商品画像も表示されてません

色々調べたところ画像が表示されない＆ダウンロードできないのは、表示方法にjavascriptとかを使っているからっぽいです。
なんとかサイト全体をオンラインで見るような形でオフラインに保存する方法はないでしょうか？

### 追記

１月５日にメンテナンスが入ってサイトがリニューアルするとのことだったので、旧商品の情報がごっそり削除される（かもしれない）前に保存しておこうと思ったんです。

調べたところ、wgetに限らず大抵のサイト保存ツールはjavascriptに対応していないようでした。 firefoxの旧拡張機能のscrapbookでは、商品画像の一部は保存されますが拡大縮小等 オンラインと同じ状態には動きません。 javascriptに対応していて、一番高性能だったのがMetaProductsが90ドルで販売しているOffline Explorerだったのですが、試用版で試したところ画像のような状態になってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

静的サイトを保存する方法はいくつかありますが、動的サイトを保存する方法は 現状ないんでしょうかね。

Comment: 何故そのようなことがしたいのでしょうか？著作権等もあるので良くない行為のような気がしますが。

Comment: 1ページ丸ごとですか？本当にサイト丸ごとですか？

Comment: wget関連だとこんな記事が参考になるかも。[wgetでサイト全体をダウンロードする](https://tex2e.github.io/blog/shell/wget-entire-website), [Node.js や curl でスクレイピング出来なくても wget で出来る場合がある](https://conveniencedailylife.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-152.html) あとは他のツールを試してみるとか？ [Cyotek WebCopy](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/library/software/cyo_webcopy/), [webサイトを丸ごとパソコンにダウンロードする方法 ～Website Explorerの使い方～](https://www.asobou.co.jp/blog/web/webex-dl), [【フリーソフト】サイトを全部取り込める「Webox」が便利すぎる！使い方を解説。](https://miyabi-blog.com/webox-sitecopy/)

Comment: @merino 写真などについて、インターネット上に違法にアップロードされたものだと知りながら侵害コンテンツをダウンロードするのは著作権法に触れますが、適法なページをダウンロードするだけであれば少なくとも著作権法で違法となる可能性は低いのではないかと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 対象サイトの利用規約は未確認ですが、サイトによってはデータの複製そのものが禁止されていることもあるためコメントいたしました。そのサイトが禁止していなければ私的利用の範囲内であれば許されるかもしれません。ただ「サイト丸ごと」というのがどうにも気になりました。勉強のためなのか、コピーサイトを作成したいのか？？質問者さんがコメントに反応しないので意図は不明ですが。

Comment: というかこの質問、プログラミング目的なのかも正直怪しいですね。

Answer (score 0):

wgetはJavaScriptを実行しません。JavaScriptで生成されるコンテンツ（によって参照される画像など）はwgetにとって知ることができないため、当然ダウンロードもされません。

参考までにWebブラウザーの設定でJavaScriptを無効化してみることで、wgetから見える世界を確認することができます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

プログラムとは全然関係無いような気がしますが…
私がやる場合はページを表示後、一番下までスクロールしてからChromeの名前をつけて保存～Webページ（完全）で保存してます。

Answer (score -1):

ブラウザの拡張機能でSingleFileという、サイト１ページまるごと保存できるプラグインがあります。画像1枚ごとにページ保存しなければなりませんがオフラインで閲覧できますよ。

Comment: これは答えになってないです。そもそも件のサイトの画像が非同期JavaScriptでロードされているものなら、そのプラグインを使用しても当質問の問題点は解決しない可能性がまだあります。